# Current core technologies for AJAX w/ Java?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jakarta-ee, integration

Looking to implement a RIA using AJAX with Java on the backend.

I was looking at DWR for an RPC style approach, but the project hasn't been updated since 2008.

I was also looking at DOJO and GWT.

Can anyone recommend a core set of technologies that works best for a Java based back end, that contains a rich set of client side widgets and backend integration with Spring WebFlow/MVC?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Spring 3.0.  It's up to date, lightweight, easily configurable, supports dependency injection, annotated classes, and is a great framework.

It supports REST, so it's easy to implement classes  that return JSON to your HTML pages.  This will help keep your content, behavior, and presentation all separate while still enabling you to build a Rich Internet Application.

Although outside the scope of your question, I'd suggest you use JQuery on the frontend as I've had really good results using it to transfer JSON back and forth from the server.

I would stay away from DWR.  They merged with Dojo, which in my opinion is a better choice than DWR.  DWR sounded good, but in practice it was buggy and difficult to use.  Dojo was much cleaner and more modular.  But unless you're using Comet (aka Reverse Ajax) just stick with Spring and JQuery.

Spring 3.0 is also supported on Google App Engine... just worth mentioning as Platform as a Service is in our future.

Comment: hmm, i see, as far as pre-built client side widgets, would we then just use the plethora of jquery plugins?

Comment: @Bill - I'd suggest using JQuery and their plug-ins..  I personally stay away from the Spring view technologies because of the negative impact they have on the web designers who aren't Java engineers.  For the most part, the JQuery plug-in styles can be controlled in the CSS, so it will still look and feel like it's part of your brand.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is a RIA framework like SmartClient or ExtJS + a REST-based backend (built on Jersey, for example).  I have also found JQuery to be extremely helpful when combined with these frameworks.  Together. this allows you to build your GUI right on top of a REST API, which itself could be reusable for programmatic integration.

These kinds of questions are always religious ones, but FWIW I am personally not a massive fan of GWT, for multiple reasons. One of those reasons is because I don't want server side folks constructing GUI-targeted data structures (I'd rather have them stick to pure data and let me GUI folks handle the GUI stuff).  So I actually don't appreciate that capability of GWT, but obviously many other people welcome that aspect, so again it's a religious choice.

Answer (score 0):

you can try GWT.That supports Spring well.
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-gwt-spring-webapp.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Spring MVC back end, you can use any AJAX frontend there is.

And if you are going to develop a RIA, I would suggest either [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) with [Script.Aculo.Us](http://script.aculo.us/) (Killer GUI effect library) or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) (which is either an extension or a re-write of prototype, that also includes many GUI tools).

The great thing about both ProtoType and Mootools is their Object-Oriented methodology ([MooTools `Class()` docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class), [Prototype `Class.create()` docs](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/class/create)), but the extension mechanism that gives additional methods and properties to DOM elements ([How Prototype extends the DOM](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/extensions), [MooTools `Element` reference](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element)). Of course this mechanism is exactly what the JQuery guys loathe about these libraries. But the nice thing is that because of these extensions, you hardly ever have to resort to browser-specific programming, the abstraction handles that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I choose JSF for RIA applications.

1. It is J2EE 6 standard
2. it built-in in J2EE application servers (glassfish, jboss),
3. it has several implementations - if you have problem with one, you can switch to another
4. I has at least 4 (richfaces, myfaces, icefaces, primefaces) independent, big components libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can work well, but my personal preference is for simplicity, and Spring is bit heavy platform. So I prefer deploying services on JAX-RS containers (like [Jersey](http://jersey.dev.java.net)); [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) for wiring things together, and in case I want to override or change data bindings, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) for JSON handling.

Other useful pieces would be [jDBI](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/04/entry_391.html) for database access (much simpler than hibernate or other full ORMs), [async-httpclient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) for doing calls to other web services.

Best of all, these all work nicely for many other kinds of uses.